# I have requirement to run my automated test cases continuously. Whats the best approach?

Tags: java, selenium, web-applications, automation

I have to run my automated test scripts of web application, continuously regardless of the status of result.please suggest me the best way/tool other than Jenkins.We are using Java,TestNG and selenium web driver.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using any Linux or Mac system you can set a `cronjob` to schedule an execution of a command (in this case your tests).

https://www.ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/

It's as easy as it can get if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repeat a single void, you can change the invocationCount to achieve the number of times at TestNG

```
@Test(priority = 1, invocationCount = 100)//run 100
public void test1() {

}
```